# How to pass get methods through DQL join query in ZF2 and Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

I’m trying to create a view that draws data from a DQL join query.  I don’t have magic getters and setters, so the view script includes get method statements like `$skill->getMeetingTitle()` that refer to functions in the entities.  When I set up the DQL statement, it doesn’t have any problem getting data from the primary table, but it won’t get data from the joined table.

```
// in the controller:

public function indexAction()
{
    $dql = "SELECT m, c FROM MyModule\Entity\SkillsMeetings m INNER JOIN m.category c ORDER BY c.categoryID, m.meetingID";
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
    $skillsList = $query->getResult();

    return array(
        'skillsList' => $skillsList,
    );
}
```

This works:

```
// in the view script:

foreach($skillsList as $skill) {
    echo $skill->getMeetingTitle() . "<br>";
}
```

This doesn’t work:

```
// in the view script:

foreach($skillsList as $skill) {
    echo $skill->getMeetingTitle() . " : ";
    echo $skill->getCategoryTitle() . "<br>";  // an element from the joined table
}
```

It gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyModule\Entity\SkillsMeetings::getCategoryTitle()
```

Comment: The **categoryTitle** seems to be a property from the **Category** entity. Try `$skill->getCategory()->getCategoryTitle()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$skill->getCategory()->getCategoryTitle()` was the answer.